# How to use Android AES encryption same as coldfusion encrypt

Tags: java, android, encryption, coldfusion, aes

We are using `coldfusion` [encrypt](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html) method on web.

```
Encrypt(plainText, key, "AES", "Hex")
```

And in `Android` we are using the encrypt method in following way:

```
public static String aesEncryption(String plainText, String key) {
        try {
            SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher aesCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            aesCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secKey);
            aesCipher.update(plainText.getBytes());
            byte[] cipherText = aesCipher.doFinal();
            return bytesToHex(cipherText);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidKeyException | NoSuchPaddingException | BadPaddingException | IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


    private static final char[] HEX_ARRAY = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    public static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            int v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = HEX_ARRAY[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = HEX_ARRAY[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

But in `Android` the output of encryption doesn't match, How to use `Android` AES encryption same as `coldfusion` `encrypt` ?

Comment: Could you post an example of the java and cf output? Use generateSecretKey() to generate a throw away key.

Comment: Why do you use ECB mode? It is not secure. In today's standards we use Authenticated Encryption modes like AES-GCM, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Coldfusion's `encrypt` uses `AES/ECB/PKCS5` padding by default when `AES` is specified as algorithm [[1]](https://cfdocs.org/encrypt). In Java/Android the provider decides which mode and padding is used if only `AES` is specified [[2]](https://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Cipher), but usually it's also `AES/ECB/PKCS5` padding (like on my machine, Android 9, API 28). Therefore the specification of the algorithm is *probably* not the cause. Nevertheless, it would be better to use the full specification `AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` in the Java code instead of `AES`.

It's possible that the key from the Coldfusion code is used incorrectly in the Java code. In Coldfusion the keys are usually generated with `generateSecretKey` [[3]](https://cfdocs.org/generatesecretkey) which returns the key Base64 encoded. This means that in the Android code the key would first have to be Base64 decoded with:

```
SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(Base64.decode(key, Base64.DEFAULT), "AES");
```

Also, if the key was generated for AES-128, no exception would be thrown because a key is 16 bytes long and Base64 encoded just 24 bytes, which in the current Android code would generate an AES key of the same length because of

```
SecretKey secKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
```

Thus, AES-192 would be used instead of AES-128, resulting in a different ciphertext of course.

*Update*: As already mentioned in the comments, ECB is an insecure mode of operation and shouldn't be used [[4]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946). A more secure alternative is CBC [[5]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_(CBC)), which is supported in both Java/Android and Coldfusion [[6]](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/cfml-reference/coldfusion-functions/functions-e-g/encrypt.html). Even more secure and modern is GCM, an authenticated encryption algorithm that guarantees both data authenticity and confidentiality [[7]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galois/Counter_Mode), which, if supported, should be preferred. Here a description of further modes can be found [[8]](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation).

Comment: `It's possible that the key is used incorrectly` That's most likely what's causing the difference. Try decoding the key as base64 and it'll probably work. Once it's working, see also the other suggestion of [using CBC instead of the default ECB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59500145/8895292).

Comment: .. and of course use the suggestion above of specifying "AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding" or "AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding" on both sides to ensure both ends are using the same settings. (CF encrypt() does support this)

Comment: No advice to not use ECB?

Answer (score 3):

Encryption requires a bit more details than just "AES", in accordance with notation it has to be something like: `AES/CBC/PKCS7Padding`, namely it should be:

```
Cipher.getInstance(transformation);
```

Where `transformation` should be consisting `[Algorithm]/[Mode]/[Padding]`, range of possible values depends on underlying cipher. For Java it's kind of:

```
AES/CBC/NoPadding
AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
AES/ECB/NoPadding
AES/ECB/PKCS5Padding
DES/CBC/NoPadding
etc...
```

If you don't specify mode and padding in this case cipher will use defaults.

I have no idea what are defaults on ColdFusion side, anyway I'd suggest to use full specs both on ColdFusion and Android sides, for instance:  `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` - is a good practice.